# How to load type library file in MSFT format using LoadTypeLibEx

Tags: c#, com, interop, typelib

I have an old `OLB` file that actually is a type library (probably MSFT file format). It´s signature starts with `0x4D, 0x53, 0x46, 0x54, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00` which is an OLE Type Libary 2, or C++ type library file, as I learned so far.

I am trying to load that file using the `LoadTypeLibEx` method in a `C#` application (a simple library viewer that can explore type libraries without registering) in order to get an `ITypLib` object that I can use to reflect all types and members defined by the library, but the function call fails with the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

Loading type libraries from other library files that do have signatures such as `0x4D, 0x5A`, or `0x53, 0x4C, 0x54, 0x47` work just fine. So, I would like to know if `LoadTypeLibEx` is able to read `MSFT` files, or what needs to be done to extract the type library that seems to be embedded into it.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2006/11/08/how-old-is-your-type-library/

Comment: @HansPassant very interesting; meanwhile I was able to tinker some code to read `OLB` files; not complete yet, but that seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @HansPassant The link is no longer valid; do you know if the information is available somewhere else?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20190110132045/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2006/11/08/how-old-is-your-type-library/